# Can't get into my desktop, linux crashes after KDE

Tags: boot, kde, desktop

I was shrinked my disk from 1TB to 800GB to leave a 200GB partition to test something, and then keeped up doing my stuff as usual, I had no problem using the computer until I turned it off, I don't know if this has something to do but it's the only thing that comes into my mind right now.

I get

> Could not load system tray icons

after loggin in and KDE plasma loads.
Then it stays on a grey desktop without nothing loading except the mouse, but I can't do any action, not even right click.

I was using the lastest version of parrot, is there any way I can run something like a troubleshooter or run something in safe mode?

Comment: if you correctly shrunk your disk, this is probably unrelated. How did you shrink your disk?

Comment: Using GParted, I know, but just wanted to give a reason of how this could happen, nothing else comes into my mind, do you have any idea how to fix it? I don't wanna loose my system configs/files